# Optimizely - How to access the variation name

Tags: php, optimizely

I am trying to create a goal in optimizly.

I have a product page product.php where someone selects a product via a radio button. That POSTS the data to the cart page. There are 3 variations plus the original one so 4 variations in total.

The data is posted something like below

```
cart.php?id=277
```

There's just 3 id's so lets say the ids are 277,278 and 279

Now i have created the variations without issue. I now want to setup a goal on the cart.php, the goals will be:

```
Product 277 added to cart
Product 278 added to cart
Product 279 added to cart
```

But essentially there will be 12 goals because there will be:

Product 277 added to cart via original
Product 277 added to cart via variation 1
Product 277 added to cart via variation 2
Product 277 added to cart via variation 3

Is there a way to do this with the custom goal or is it only possible via the API? I found the documentation on their site a bit confusing and couldn't find anything specifically related to this, been waiting a few days for a reply from their support with no reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually just code 3 goals (one for each product) or even a single goal ('add to cart clicks') and then do the pivoting in the reporting section where it will break everything out by variation (see screenshot).

That said, `optimizely.variationNamesMap[1234567890]` where 1234567890 is the experiment ID (pull from the querystring on the edit page) will allow you to access your variation names in the code.

[image: Shows how you pivot by variation]

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help. Im pretty much brand new to optimizely so i was hoping you could go into a bit more detail as im not sure exactly how to apply this. On my product page when i run the page and type: alert(optimizely.variationNamesMap[0123456789]); in the browser console (where i replaced 012... with the experiment id) and it comes back as undefined)

Comment: You have to actually be bucketed into a variation for that experiment. Check out the Optimizely QA Article on setting a test cookie and then push your experiment live. It should work once you're bucketed.